OAuth2 Authorization code flow with PKCE Access Token request
I am developing a webapp with Spring-Boot, Angular and Keycloak. I am using the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE. The current auth flow is the following:

User is sent to Keycloak login page
User logs in and gets the auth code and Keycloak authenticates the user and sets session cookies.
angular sends code_verifier and auth code to Keycloak to get access
token

After this the access token is sent for accessing sensetive resources in backend and they are fetched accordingly. Now my problem is that i have noticed that when i refresh the page or go to another page, the third step is repeated and the same auth code is sent to get a new access token. is this intented behaviour? shouldnt the access token be fetched once and be used without having to get a new one every time? this is how i initialized the Keycloak in angular:
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: environment.keycloakurl,
        realm: 'realm',
        clientId: 'client',
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required'
      }
    });
}


This question is similar to: How to retrieve the code verifier using Keycloak from Angular. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That topic has not much to do with my question. I am more so asking how the auth flow is done and if my current implementation where the token is requested everytime on a page reload is intented

In the PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange) authentication flow, when using Keycloak with its official keycloak.js library, the Angular component does not need to handle the code verifier or exchange the code for a token directly. keycloak.js library abstracts the PKCE flow, including generating the code verifier, creating the code challenge, and exchanging the authorization code for tokens (access token and refresh token). No, requesting the token every time a page or component reloads is not intended in most cases when using Keycloak or any other OAuth 2 implementation.Token persistence in it.

During the initial login flow, tokens (access token and refresh token) are fetched and stored in the browser, typically in memory, localStorage, or sessionStorage.
On a page reload, keycloak.js should restore the session using stored tokens, refresh the token if it's expired, and avoid initiating a new login flow unless the session has expired entirely.

Tokens should not be sent to an Angular app. Using the OAuth2 BFF pattern should be preferred.
